# Django unit test - patch multiple requests for external api

Tags: django

I need to write 'one' test code with external api, which requires requests 'twice'.

first, I need to check if user is valid.
So I handled this with decorator in **./users/utils.py**

```py
import requests

def login_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # this access token is issued by external api
        access_token = request.headers.get('Authorization', None)

        # first requests, which gives me an info about user.
        response  = requests.get(
            'https://kapi.kakao.com/v2/user/me', 
            headers={'Authorization':f'Bearer {access_token}'}
        )

        user_email = response.json()['kakao_account']['email']
 
        request.user = User.objects.get(email=user_email)

        return func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

and then, I need to send that user a message with the external api again.
this code is in **./bids/views.py**

```py
import requests

class BiddingView(View):
    #it uses login_decorator above
    @login_decorator
    def post(self, request, art_id):
        try:
            user = request.user
            data = json.loads(request.body)

            with transaction.atomic():
                #handle things with bidding system#

                #the external api requires its token to use a message api.
                token = request.headers.get('Authorization', None)

                #second requests, with post method
                response = requests.post(
                    'https://kapi.kakao.com/v2/api/talk/memo/default/send',
                    headers = {'Authorization'   : f'Bearer {token}'},
                    data    = {"template_object" : json.dumps({'message':'contents'})}
                )

            return JsonResponse({'MESSAGE' : 'SUCCESS'}, status=200)

        except KeyError:
            return JsonResponse({'MESSAGE' : 'KEY ERROR'}, status=400)
```

This is my unit test code about BiddingView so far, which obviously only works for decorator

```py
@patch('users.utils.requests')
def test_kakao_message_success(self, mock_requests):
    class MockResponse:
        def json(self):
            return {'kakao_account' : {'email' : 'test@test.com'}}

    mock_requests.get = MagicMock(return_value=MockResponse())

    header   = {'HTTP_Authorization' : 'ACCESS_TOKEN'}

    body = {'offered_price' : 10000}

    response = client.post(
        '/bidding/1',
        json.dumps(body),
        content_type='application/json', **header
    )
```

but I need to patch both **.users.utils.requests** and **.bids.views.requests** for my mock test.

```py
@patch('users.utils.requests') # + @patch('bids.views.requests')
def test_kakao_message_success(self, mock_requests):
```

I want to know how to patch two requests at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your source code for ease of testing so that we can concentrate on the problem which are the external requests.

**./utils.py**

```
import requests

def login_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # first requests, which gives me an info about user.
        response  = requests.get(
            'https://kapi.kakao.com/v2/user/me', 
            headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer access_token'}
        )

        request.user = response.json()['kakao_account']['email']
 
        return func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

**./views.py**

```
import json
import requests

from utils import login_decorator


class BiddingView:
    #it uses login_decorator above
    @login_decorator
    def post(self, request, art_id):
        print(f"The current user is {request.user}")

        #second requests, with post method
        response = requests.post(
            'https://kapi.kakao.com/v2/api/talk/memo/default/send',
            headers = {'Authorization'   : 'Bearer token'},
            data    = {"template_object" : json.dumps({'message':'contents'})}
        )

        return response.text
```

### Solution 1 - Manual patching of requests for each source file

You can stack the unittest.mock.patch decorator, one after the other.

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

from views import BiddingView


class MockLoginResponse:
    def json(self):
        return {'kakao_account' : {'email' : 'test@test.com'}}


class MockViewResponse:
    text = "He alone, who owns the youth, gains the future."


@patch('utils.requests.get', MagicMock(return_value=MockLoginResponse()))
@patch('views.requests.post', MagicMock(return_value=MockViewResponse()))
def test_kakao_message_success():
    response = BiddingView().post(
        request=MagicMock(),
        art_id="some art"
    )
    print(f"Response: {response}")
```

Output:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________ test_kakao_message_success ___________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The current user is test@test.com
Response: He alone, who owns the youth, gains the future.
```

### Solution 2.1 - Instead of patching requests per file, patch the exact target request

This requires you to install library https://pypi.org/project/requests-mock/

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

import requests_mock

from views import BiddingView


def test_kakao_message_success_with_library():
    with requests_mock.Mocker() as requests_mocker:
        # Mock the external requests
        requests_mocker.get(
            "https://kapi.kakao.com/v2/user/me",
            json={'kakao_account' : {'email' : 'test@test.com'}},
        )
        requests_mocker.post(
            "https://kapi.kakao.com/v2/api/talk/memo/default/send",
            text="He alone, who owns the youth, gains the future.",
        )

        response = BiddingView().post(
            request=MagicMock(),
            art_id="some art"
        )
        print(f"Response: {response}")
```

Output:

- Same as above

### Solution 2.2 - Instead of patching requests per file, patch the exact target request. But now, apply it automatically to any test using pytest's autouse feature.

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

import pytest
import requests_mock

from views import BiddingView


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def setup_external_requests():
    with requests_mock.Mocker() as requests_mocker:
        # Mock the external requests
        requests_mocker.get(
            "https://kapi.kakao.com/v2/user/me",
            json={'kakao_account' : {'email' : 'test@test.com'}},
        )
        requests_mocker.post(
            "https://kapi.kakao.com/v2/api/talk/memo/default/send",
            text="He alone, who owns the youth, gains the future.",
        )

        # It is required to perform a yield instead of return to not teardown the requests_mocker
        yield requests_mocker


def test_kakao_message_success_with_library_2():
    response = BiddingView().post(
        request=MagicMock(),
        art_id="some art"
    )
    print(f"Response: {response}")
```

Output:

- Same as above